# Poles with different behaviours

Tags: real-analysis, functions, asymptotics

Is there a difference between the names of the poles at $x=0$ between:

1) $f(x)=\dfrac1x$

2) $f(x)=\dfrac1{|x|}$

in that (1) tends to $+\infty$ as $x\to0^+$, and to $-\infty$ as $x\to0^-$, whereas (2) tends to $+\infty$ from either side.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I am aware, a **pole** can only be possessed by a function on an open subset of $\mathbb C$ (or more generally a Riemann surface) that is analytic in a deleted neighbourhood of the pole.  $1/|x|$ is not analytic in a deleted neighbourhood of $0$ in $\mathbb C$, so it does not have a pole there.

Comment: are there other functions that are analytic in DNP's and portray either form of pole?

Comment: You mean like $1/x^2$?

Comment: yes, exactly like that